# Using SVN kit Not able to add the file to repository and the below code is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, svnkit

I am not able to add any file in the repository using editor, it is throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception at line `editor.addFile(textfile, null, -1);`

```
try {
    url = "https://XXX.yyy.zzzz";
    SVNRepository repository = null;
    String name = "testuser";
    String password = "testuserpassword";
    repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url));
    ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(name, password);
    repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    System.out.println(repository.getLatestRevision());

    SVNClientInterface client = SVNClientImpl.newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error");
}               

try { 
    ISVNEditor editor = repository.getCommitEditor("This is a log message.", new CommitMediator()); 

    editor.openRoot(-1); 
    System.out.println("in DAV");
    editor.addFile(textfile, null, -1);
    editor.addFile("file1.txt", null, -1);       
    editor.applyTextDelta("file1.txt", null); 
    OutputStream os=null;
    os.close(); 
    editor.textDeltaEnd(file1.txt); 
    editor.closeFile(file1.txt, null); 
    editor.closeEdit(); 
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to add any file in the repository using editor, it is throwing an java.lang.NullPointerException exception at line "editor.addFile(textfile, null, -1); "   Thanks in Advance

Comment: `os.close();` after `OutputStream os=null;` means `NullPointerException` for sure.

Comment: If you don't want to use log4j or something for logging, at least replace `System.out.println(e);` with `e.printStackTrace();`, please!

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.addFile(textfile, null, -1);
```

What's `textfile`?

```
OutputStream os=null;
os.close();
```

Might want to think about what's happening right there.

Comment: "textfile" is the name of the text file which i want to add to the repository

Comment: @user1118693 - Yes, but where is it defined? For all we know, it's `null`.